# How to add dynamic steps like dynamic data to automation testing

Tags: automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, build-automation

Having test with iterations which is steps like

Iteration 1 click on button in page Iteration 2 click on button in page 2 with same steps and same insertions.
I don’t want to repeat test case.

Answer (score 0):

Test case steps can be dynamic like data by passing actions and func.

For example we need to automate reports page which have buttons for report1, report2, ..., report 10, when any button is clicked, confirming popup is displayed. This test case can be automated in one test case by passing dynamic steps to test case so no need to repeat test case.

For example nuit TestCaseSource returns IEnumerable.

```
GetTestCaseData IEnumerable<TestCaseData> (){
Yield return new Action( () =>      report1.Click())
```

.
.

```
}
```

By passing this method to test case like below. There is no need for repeating test cases by dividing iterations to different test cases. Iterations can be passed to test case.

```
    [Test,TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestCaseData))]
Public void TestCase (Action report){

//Act
NavigateToReport();
report.Invoke();

//Assert
}
```

Action can be used when no need to return. Func can be used if you need to assert on return.